# My android app is crashing. Below is the stack trace

Tags: android

// this the stacktrace

> 03-29 20:39:18.104 19262-19262/com.example.monkchatv1
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.monkchatv1, PID: 19262
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.monkchatv1/com.example.monkchatv1.MainActivity}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #27: Error
>   inflating class ImageView
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2505)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:164)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1462)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:160)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5541)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:964)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:759)
>        Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #27: Error inflating class ImageView
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:763)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
>           at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555)
>           at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161)
>           at com.example.monkchatv1.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:48)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6093)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2458)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:164) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1462) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:160) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5541) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:964) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:759) 
>        Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource "com.example.monkchatv1:drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"
>   (7f07006f)  is not a Drawable (color or path):
>   TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f07006f a=-1 r=0x7f07006f}
>           at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2602)
>           at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2538)
>           at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:749)
>           at android.widget.ImageView.(ImageView.java:146)
>           at android.widget.ImageView.(ImageView.java:135)
>           at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView.(AppCompatImageView.java:72)
>           at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView.(AppCompatImageView.java:68)
>           at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createImageView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:187)
>           at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:107)
>           at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1407)
>           at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1457)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:725)

Answer (score 0):

check imageView (may be at line 27) in xml file, system can not find drawable that you have set in xml file.
try to set another drawable/color and check if crash persists .

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from an ImageView that you created in MainActivity. Try to comment it from the XML file and all the references to this image view from your Java / Kotlin file.

Then, start to uncomment first the ImageView from XML file, then each line with image view reference from Java / Kotlin file.

If you could share us the code from your MainActivity (both files), maybe we could help you a little more.